# $e^x>1+(1+x)\log(1+x)$,for $x>0$ using infinite series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

$e^x>1+(1+x)\log(1+x)$,for $x>0$ using infinite series.

Attempt
$\sum x^k(\frac{1}{k!}+\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k!}+\frac{(-1)^{k+1}x}{k!})>1$.

any hints?

Comment: The series for the term $\log(1+x)$ only converges for $x<1$ so maybe this series approach can only show the inequality for $x \in (0,1).$

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove the case 0 < x < 1: ln(1 + x) = x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 - x^4/4 + x^5/5 -....
so multiply this with (1 + x) and get: 1 + (1 + x)ln(1 + x) = 1 + x + x^2/2 - x^3/6 - x^4/12 - x^5/20 -...- x^n/((n-1)n) -... < 1 + x + x^2/2 < e^x.

For the case x > 1, put y = 1/x and get back to case 1 after some simplifying steps. I am sure it won't be very hard to prove this case.

Answer (score 0):

Estimating the integral $\int_1^{1+x}dt/t = \log(1+x)$ by the area of a trapezoid between $t=1$ and $t=1+x$ shows $$\log(1+x)< \frac{x(2+x)}{2(1+x)}$$ for all $x>0$ and therefore $$1+(1+x)\log(1+x)<1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}<e^x.$$